# How verify mysql database connection from another file php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've created a form where the user can add his database name, username, password, host. then that form creates a config file and adds the user database details. the form is in root and the config file is in root/includes. I want to know how can I verify database connection from form file. if the connection is successful he can proceed to the next step and if it's not I want to show the error.

**Form**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['db-details']) {

    $dbName = $_POST['dbName'];
    $dbUsername = $_POST['dbUsername'];
    $dbPassword = $_POST['dbPassword'];
    $dbHost = $_POST['dbHost'];

    $phConfigFile = 'includes/ph_config.php';

    file_put_contents($phConfigFile, $phConfigData);

}
```

**Config**

```
<?php 

    define("DB_HOST", "[dbHost]");

    define("DB_USER", "[dbUsername]");

    define("DB_PASS", "[dbPassword]");

    define("DB_NAME", "[dbName]");

    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

Comment: it would be great if you share the key parts of the code, so we can see how it is made.

Comment: Are you giving an individual database to each of your users?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Nope, It's an application like Wordpress. when the user extract the zip he can add his database details and the application will install if the connection is successful

Comment: Well simply put the $_POST variables into a connection attempt and check the result

Comment: So you want to use a HTML form to generate a db config file?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I already added the data received from the form to the connection. want to verify the connection from form.php file. I think if the file_put_contents is success include ph_config and then test the connection and proceed to next

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I already created that. this form creates a DB connection now just need to verify it.

Comment: Seems you have an answer already. Why don't you try, and come back when it doesn't work?

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same as RiggsFolly answer, but improved.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['db-details'])) {
    try {
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        $connection = new mysqli(
            $_POST['dbHost'],
            $_POST['dbUsername'],
            $_POST['dbPassword'],
            $_POST['dbName']
        );

        $DBconfig = [
            'dbHost' => $_POST['dbHost'],
            'dbUsername' => $_POST['dbUsername'],
            'dbPassword' => $_POST['dbPassword'],
            'dbName' => $_POST['dbName']
        ];

        // generate the config file
        $contents = '<?php' . PHP_EOL;
        $contents .= '$DBconfig = ' . var_export($DBconfig, true) . ';' . PHP_EOL;
        $contents .= 'mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);' . PHP_EOL;
        $contents .= '$connection = new mysqli(
            $DBconfig["dbHost"],
            $DBconfig["dbUsername"],
            $DBconfig["dbPassword"],
            $DBconfig["dbName"]
        );';
        echo $contents;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // echo error message here and show the same form. 
    }
}
```

Basically, you should avoid the error suppression operator at all cost. Thankfully PHP has exceptions, which can be caught and handled.

If there's no exception you can put the connection details in an array and then export that array into a string. Generate the connection file and save it.

Another thing I would improve is to encapsulate this in a function to prevent the config details spilling out.

```
// generate the config file
$contents = '<?php' . PHP_EOL;
$contents .= 'function db_connect():\mysqli { '. PHP_EOL;
$contents .= '$DBconfig = ' . var_export($DBconfig, true) . ';' . PHP_EOL;
$contents .= 'mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);' . PHP_EOL;
$contents .= 'return new mysqli(
    $DBconfig["dbHost"],
    $DBconfig["dbUsername"],
    $DBconfig["dbPassword"],
    $DBconfig["dbName"]
);';
$contents .= PHP_EOL;
$contents .= '}'.PHP_EOL;
$contents .= '$connection = db_connect();'.PHP_EOL;
echo $contents;
```

Answer (score 2):

You really want to check the connection before you create the config file, so once created you know it will work

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['db-details']) {

    $dbName     = $_POST['dbName'];
    $dbUsername = $_POST['dbUsername'];
    $dbPassword = $_POST['dbPassword'];
    $dbHost     = $_POST['dbHost'];

    // use error supression so you get to process the error rather 
    // than PHP throwing an error
    $connection = @mysqli_connect($_POST['dbHost'], 
                                $_POST['dbUsername'], 
                                $_POST['dbPassword'], 
                                $_POST['dbName']);

    if ( ! $connection ) {
        // do whatever you need to when the information passed does not work
        exit;
    }

    // must be valid as we connected

    $str = '<?php' . PHP_EOL;
    $str .= 'define("DB_HOST", "' . $_POST['dbHost'] . '");'        . PHP_EOL;
    $str .= 'define("DB_USER", "' . $_POST['dbUsername'] . '");'    . PHP_EOL;
    $str .= 'define("DB_PASS", "' . $_POST['dbPassword'] . '");'    . PHP_EOL;
    $str .= 'define("DB_NAME", "' . $_POST['dbName'] . '");'        . PHP_EOL; 

    $str .= '$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);' . PHP_EOL;

    // create the config file in all confidence that the values will work
    file_put_contents($phConfigFile, $str);    
}
```

Comment: This applies to both answers: I don't think you can use `$connection->connect_errno` on a failed connection. `mysqli_connect()` will return `false`. But I must say - I would also check the connection before i generate a potentially invalid config file.

Comment: Hi @PaulSpiegel I did say I would check connection (as I am doing) before creatig the config file? Or were you just agreeing with me??

Comment: Yes - just agreeing.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Hmm you are right about the connection test I think though :)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Bit of testing and I find (so its a good day I learned something) that if you suppress errors on the connect you will get to process the error yourself

Comment: This is how they do it in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php) - a good source for bad practice ;-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you! I think using error suppression is a better way

Comment: I really don't think suppressing errors is the best way to go here. This is actually something to avoid. Why not simply use try-catch?

Comment: Also putting user data directly into PHP executable is open to RCE. Don't ever do it!

Answer (score 0):

So if i get you right, you want to know if the data the user enters is actually valid to connect to a server. Not validating it.

You can include the file you just wrote and test it.

Just make sure you're using the same variable name after the include.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['db-details']) {

 $dbName = $_POST['dbName'];
 $dbUsername = $_POST['dbUsername'];
 $dbPassword = $_POST['dbPassword'];
 $dbHost = $_POST['dbHost'];

 $phConfigFile = 'includes/ph_config.php';

 file_put_contents($phConfigFile, $phConfigData);

 include($phConfigFile);

 if ($connection->connect_errno) {
  //data for the connection isn't valid
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $connection->connect_error;
  exit();
 }

}
```

Comment: Yep, I did the same thing but in a procedural way. thanks buddy for your time